# Create PySpark Profile for IPython

Tags: python, apache-spark

I follow this link http://ramhiser.com/2015/02/01/configuring-ipython-notebook-support-for-pyspark/  in order to create PySpark Profile for IPython.

```
00-pyspark-setup.py
# Configure the necessary Spark environment
import os
import sys

spark_home = os.environ.get('SPARK_HOME', None)
sys.path.insert(0, spark_home + "\python")

# Add the py4j to the path.
# You may need to change the version number to match your install
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(spark_home, '\python\lib\py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip'))

# Initialize PySpark to predefine the SparkContext variable 'sc'
execfile(os.path.join(spark_home, '\python\pyspark\shell.py'))
```

My problem when I type `sc` in ipython-notebook, I got `''` I  should see output similar to `<pyspark.context.SparkContext at 0x1097e8e90>.`

Any idea about how to resolve it ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve. Where in your code does the problem occur?

Comment: In Python 3 execfile was removed so last line have to be changed to exec(open(os.path.join(spark_home, '\python\pyspark\shell.py')).read()).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was trying to do the same, but had problems. Now, I use `findspark` (https://github.com/minrk/findspark) instead. You can install it with pip (see https://pypi.python.org/pypi/findspark/):

```
$ pip install findspark
```

And then, inside a notebook:

```
import findspark
findspark.init()

import pyspark
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(appName="myAppName")
```

If you want to avoid this boilerplate, you can put the above 4 lines in `00-pyspark-setup.py`.

(Right now I have Spark 1.4.1. and findspark 0.0.5.)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to set proper value to `SPARK_LOCAL_IP` variable, eg.:

```
export SPARK_LOCAL_IP="$(hostname -f)"
```

before you run `ipython notebook --profile=pyspark`.

If this doesn't help, try to debug your environment by executing setup script:

```
python 00-pyspark-setup.py
```

Maybe you can find some error lines in that way and debug them.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on windows? I am dealing with the same things, and a couple of things helped. 
In the 00-pyspark-setup.py, change this line (match your path to your spark folder)

```
# Configure the environment
if 'SPARK_HOME' not in os.environ:
    print 'environment spark not set'
    os.environ['SPARK_HOME'] = 'C:/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6'
```

I am sure you added a new environment variable, if not, this will manually set it.

The next thing I noticed is that if you use ipython 4 (the latest), the config files don't work the same way you see it in all the tutorials. You can try out if your config files get called by adding a print statement or just messing them up so an error gets thrown.

I am using a lower version of iPython (3) and I call it using

```
ipython notebook --profile=pyspark
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `00-pyspark-setup.py` to:

```
# Configure the necessary Spark environment
import os

# Spark home
spark_home = os.environ.get("SPARK_HOME")

######## CODE ADDED ########
os.environ["PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS"] = "--master local[2] pyspark-shell"
######## END OF ADDED CODE #########

sys.path.insert(0, spark_home + "/python")
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(spark_home, 'python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip'))

# Initialize PySpark to predefine the SparkContext variable 'sc'
execfile(os.path.join(spark_home, 'python/pyspark/shell.py'))
```

Basically, the added code sets the PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS environment variable to

`--master local[2] pyspark-shell`, which works for Spark 1.6 standalone.

Now run ipython notebook again. Run `os.environ["PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS"]` to check whether its value is correctly set. If so, then type `sc` should give you the expected output like `<pyspark.context.SparkContext at 0x1097e8e90>`